# bind return value and variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, threadpool, variadic-templates

I am trying to create a Thread Pool in C++. The concept is that main will create a new Task and the ThreadPool class will get the Task objects and implement the other work. This is the Task class:

```
template<typename ... Arguments>
        class Task{
            //
        public:
            Task(std::function<void (Arguments...)> _func, Arguments... _args){
                auto f1 = std::bind(_func, _args...);
                f1();
            };
            void run(){

            };
        };
```

and this how i am trying to use it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include "Task.hpp"

void prtinhi(int a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main(){

    Task<int> task(prtinhi, 5);
    task.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously the Task object will be passed in the ThreadPool and the ThreadPool will call run() according to some logic.
This codes run successfully printing 5. But what i want is to call f1() from the run() function. If i change Task class to have the `auto f1` defintion as a class member i get an error:

```
non-static data member declared ‘auto’
```

if i declare it static i can't assign a value to it.
So how do i solve this one? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `decltype` perhaps?

Comment: I don't get how can decltype help me here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does the task need to know about the function arguments? The task should be a `void()` type-erased callable object.

```
using Task = std::function<void()>;
Task task([]{ prtinhi(5); });

ThreadPool pool;
pool.schedule(task);
// ...
// `prtinhi(5)` will be eventually called.
```

If you need to get the return value, you want [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

`ThreadPool` could be implemented as follows:

```
struct ThreadPool
{
    some_lockfree_queue<Task> _queue;
    std::vector<std::thread> _workers;

    void initialize()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
        {
            _workers.emplace_back([this]
            { 
                Task t = _queue.try_dequeue();
                t();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

---

`std::bind` is **bad** *(watch [this talk by STL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0) for more info)*. You should use [**lambdas**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to bind the arguments you require and get a nullary function back.